# Flattened form in WAM

Tags: prolog, warren-abstract-machine

The WAM: A Tutorial Reconstruction states that a query, p(Z, h(Z,W), f(W)), needs to be flattened using the following principles:

[image]

That being said, the query flattened form is:

```
X3=h(X2, X5), X4=f(X5), X1=p(X2, X3, X4);
```

I am lost with the definition of external variable, consider the following:

```
p(Z, h(Y, a(K, C), b(W)), f(W)).
```

Is Y an external variable? How should be the flattened form for this? From my understanding this would be the construction:

```
X1 = p(X2, X3, X4)
X2 = Z
X3 = h(X5, X6, X7)
X4 = f(X8)
X5 = Y
X6 = a(X7, X8)
X7 = K
X8 = C
X9 = b(X5)
```

But I am not sure, starting at X4 I got confused, should I have assigned the h inner values first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the order the wrong way around: You are building terms before you have built their arguments. The text says to build the arguments before you build the outer terms. For example, you must build `a(K, C)` before you can build `h(..., a(K, C), ...)`, and you must build that before you can build `p(..., h(..., a(K, C), ...), ...)`. Here is one legal order:

```
X7 = K
X8 = C
X6 = a(X7, X8)
X5 = Y
X9 = b(X5)
X2 = Z
X3 = h(X5, X6, X7)
X4 = f(X8)
X1 = p(X2, X3, X4)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know any algorithms to implement this? I was thinking of using a tree and some recursion, but I am not sure if it will work.

Comment: Yes, a term is a tree, and recursion is the way to do this. For any functor, first generate its argument terms recursively, then generate the functor itself.