# WAM register allocation for same structures

Tags: prolog, warren-abstract-machine

Warren’s Abstract Machine A Tutorial Reconstruction states the following for Variable Register Allocation rules:

- Variable registers are allocated according to least available index.
- Register X1 is always allocated to the outermost term.
- A same register is allocated to all the occurrences of
  a given variable.

Further in the tutorial, while building program queries, the following example is given:

```
p(f(X), h(Y, f(a)), Y).

X1 = p(X2, X3, X4)
X2 = f(X5)
X3 = h(X4, X6)
X4 = Y
X5 = X
X6 = f(X7)
X7 = a
```

My doubt is when considering the two occurrences of the f clause, both are f/1 structures, but with a different body and therefore needed to be instantiated differently. But what exactly is considered a variable in the WAM context, a prolog variable, or every term? How would the clause `p(f(a), f(a))` be constructed:

```
X1 = p(X2, X2)
X2 = f(X3)
X3 = a
```

or

```
X1 = p(X2, X3)
X2 = f(X4)
X3 = f(X4)
X4 = a
```

Comment: have a look at the accepted answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64814365/flattened-form-in-wam?rq=1

Comment: That was my own question. That was about query construction, program terms are built differently